# ViewChanged suppress on Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: events, bing-maps, windows-phone-8.1

There is a way to fire the event `ViewChanged` (that was present in previous WP8) within an Windows Phone 8.1 app? I use `Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Maps` and I will manage the map when the view animation finishes.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use on of these events of the MapControl class:

- ManipulationStarted: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh702372.aspx
- CenterChanged: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows.ui.xaml.controls.maps.mapcontrol.centerchanged.aspx
- ZoomLevelChanged: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows.ui.xaml.controls.maps.mapcontrol.zoomlevelchanged.aspx

But the best event would be ManipulationCompleted: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows.ui.xaml.uielement.manipulationcompleted.aspx

Comment: I don't need CenterChanged and ZoomLevelChanged because they fires the the event during the animations or during "every" single change. I just wanna fire the event when the changes are finished. The ManipulationCompleted event seems not work properly (it doesn't fire events when I zoom/move the map).

Answer (score 0):

I've found that the `LoadingStatusChanged` event does what you want, provided you check the `LoadingStatus` first.

```
mapControl.LoadingStatusChanged += MapLoadingStatusChanged;

private void MapLoadingStatusChanged(MapControl sender, object args)
{
    if (sender.LoadingStatus == MapLoadingStatus.Loaded)
    {
        // code here will only get hit when the map finishes drawing after a pan/zoom
    }
}
```